# React hooks - Prevent rerender if parent state that holds children props changed

Tags: reactjs, optimization, react-hooks, react-typescript, rerender

I have an issue with my current project that uses react hooks.
What I'm trying to do is just to select my tasks by using (`shift+click`). Look like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```js
  ...
  const [selectedTaskIds, setSelectedTaskIds] = useState<string[]>([])
  const selectTask = useCallback(
    (e: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>, taskId: string): void => {
      e.stopPropagation()

      const previousTaskId = selectedTaskIds[selectedTaskIds.length - 1]
      if (previousTaskId && e.shiftKey) {
        // handle shift+click
        const previousIdx = tasks.findIndex((task) => task.id === previousTaskId)
        const selectedIdx = tasks.findIndex((task) => task.id === taskId)
        const rangeTasks =
          previousIdx < selectedIdx
            ? tasks.slice(previousIdx, selectedIdx + 1)
            : tasks.slice(selectedIdx, previousIdx + 1)
        const rangeIds = rangeTasks.map((task) => task.id)
        setSelectedTaskIds([...new Set([...selectedTaskIds, ...rangeIds])])
      } else {
        // if no key clicked, just select 1 task item
        setSelectedTaskIds([taskId])
      }
    },
    [selectedTaskIds, tasks] // <==== in here I notice that activeTaskIds is changed overtime that causes all of my <TaskItem> rerender
  )

  return (
      {tasks.map((task) => (
          <TaskItem
            key={task.id}
            taskId={task.id}
            onClick={selectTask} // <=== selectTask will be different if user click on one of the task items
            active={selectedTaskIds.includes(task.id)}
          />
        ))}
   )
```

The problem is, to know which tasks should I select when the user uses `shift+click`, I need to know the currently selected task ids, so that I need to pass `selectedTaskIds` as a `useCallback()` deps.

That makes whenever the user selects the tasks or even just a click on one of the task items to select the task, it will re-render **all** of my `<TaskItem>` since the `selectTask()` function change due to useCallback's deps changed.

How can I solve this without rerender all of my `<TaskItem>`s? Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you try without passing any `deps` to the `useCallback` (I mean empty `[]`)? What happens then?

Comment: yes I did, it won't rerender all children but when I select multiple task items with `shift+click`, it doesn't work as expected (only 1 item get selected)

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code on my machine and tested out a few scenarios. As far as I can tell, it looks natural for the component to re-render the all of the `<TaskItem>`s because any change in the `selectedTaskIds` state will guarantee  everything inside the component that holds `selectedTaskIds` to render. To show you a concrete example,

```
<div className="App">
    <TaskItems />
    <div>hahaha</div>
    <div>selectedTaskIds</div>
</div>
```

Let's say you have the above code. (I named your component that holds multiple `<TaskItem/>`s as `<TaskItems/>`) When `onClick` of `<TaskItem/>` triggers, only `<TaskItems/>` will re-render. The two other divs are not re-rendered. However, if you place the two divs inside the `<TaskItems/>` component, they will re-render:

```
// assuming this is inside <TaskItems/>
...
return (
<div>
  {tasks.map((task) => (
      <TaskItem
        key={task.id}
        taskId={task.id}
        onClick={(e) => { selectTask2(e, task.id)}} // <=== selectTask will be different if user click on one of the task items
        // active={selectedTaskIds.includes(task.id)}
        active={true}
        title={task.title}
      />
    ))}
    <div>hahaha</div>
    <div>selectedTaskIds</div>
</div>
```

);

above code will re-render the two divs.

I have tried to fulfill your request to get rid of the re-renders of the tasks that weren't changed, but it was really hard to do so. When I try to prevent re-rendering I usually use one of the two techniques:

> 1. create a child component and separate the code base to isolate groups of states. (since states are what triggers renders, you can
>    separate unrelated ones into different groups.)
> 2. useCallback/useMemo

Either techniques I failed to implement for your case, but there may be a way to apply the above techniques. I will follow the thread to see if anyone else gets a solution.

Comment: I will update the post for the next few hours if I come up with something.

Comment: Hi Seho, thanks so much for trying! yeah I also try to figure it out but couldn't find a better way to get rid of rerenders of other tasks :( I also thinking to separate the component but I think the result will be the same since it will need the selectedTaskIds eventually